# mariadb issue with create table select where the select is a union

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb, union, create-table

I have a six-way union select that I am working with that is part of a PHP script. The command works fine in the script. In executing from the SQL client, the command also works fine. However, when I try to put the SELECT inside a CREATE TABLE mytable SELECT, I get an error message as follows:

```
Incorrect column name ''
```

In five of the union segments, there is a column name '', which is a placeholder for data filled in later in the script. But in one of the unions there is varchar(32) column in that same place.

It seems that the command as executed normally does not care that there is an "anonymous" column. But in the CREATE TABLE version is does not like that.

Why are there different rules for the SELECT and CREATE TABLE SELECT for union column names?

Comment: show the complete query please

Comment: The error message indicates that your `SELECT` returns a column named `''`. You probably forgot to provide an alias for it, e.g. `SELECT '' AS colname, ...`

Comment: When you use a UNION, the column names all come from the first query in the union. So if you have placeholder values, you need to name them in the first query.

Comment: These two coments from Barmar seem to have the correct answer. The answer below from O. Jones also has the same correct answer, but it cam in a few minutes later. In the interest of fairness, if the Barmar comments were made into answers I would give partial credit to each if possible.

Comment: I was hoping that Barmar would provide an answer that I could select because the comments came in slightly before the answer below. But since that has not occurred, to close this question I am selecting the O. Jones answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables can't contain columns with blank or missing names. Result sets can. And `CREATE TABLE SELECT` gets the table's column names from the column names in the `SELECT` statement's result set. Therefore you need to make sure each column of your result set has a name, derived either from a column in some table, or from an `AS` alias.  For example,

```sql
SELECT 'one' AS tablename, cola, colb, colc FROM table_one
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'two',              cola, colb, colc FROM table_two
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'three',            cola, colb, colc FROM table_three
```

is suitable for use in a CREATE TABLE statement, whereas

```sql
SELECT 'one',   cola, colb, colc FROM table_one
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'two',   cola, colb, colc FROM table_two
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'three', cola, colb, colc FROM table_three
```

is not, because you it does not assign an alias column name to the first column.